# Using latexindent from vi?

Tags: vim, latexindent

I would like to use `latexindent` from the `vi` editor.
Ideally, I would use it just like one uses `fmt`.
Recall that in `vi` you can filter any portion of your text through an external filter. So, one could type `!}fmt` and upon hitting return, the current paragraph is formatted as if it was text. Similarly, you can type `!}sort -u` to sort a list, removing any duplicates, etc.

Ideally, one could write `!}latexindet -someflags` to LaTeX format the current paragraph.

Benefits of this workflow are being able to quickly undo the changes by simply hitting `u`, and the ability to apply indentation at a finer grain.

I will wait a little, before posting my answer to this problem.

Comment: I have `nmap <Tab> ==` and `vmap <Tab> ==` in my `.vimrc`. With these definitions I can indent the current line according to its surroundings by pressing "Tab" in command mode. In visual mode I can also select some lines and press "Tab". (maybe needs `set autoindent`)

Comment: I use `arara` [youtubde demonstration](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_AMmNVg5WM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a bash script named, say, `ind` whose content is:

```
#!/bin/sh -f
cat > /tmp/$$ 
latexindent -l /tmp/$$
```

make it executable, and add it to your path. Then type `!}ind`.